# MySQL left join not working with AS keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I like to use self explaining names for associative selects, and sometimes it's even mandatory to avoid duplicates, so I use the AS keyword alot. But it's giving me some trouble with left joins.

This works:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
        projects.id as projects_id
       FROM projects";

$sql .= " LEFT JOIN".
    " (SELECT 
        projectfiles.id as projectfiles_id,
        projectfiles.fileID as projectfiles_fileID,
        projectfiles.projectID as projectfiles_projectID
       FROM projectfiles
       ) AS projectfiles".
    " ON projects.id = projectfiles_projectID";
```

However now I end up with useless data from `projects`, because it also picks up the fields `userID` and `name`, which I don't need. It's also picking up the id twice.

So I tried changing it to;

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        projects.id as projects_id
       FROM projects";
```

With the ON line becoming

```
" ON projects_id = projectfiles_projectID";
```

But that gave the error `Unknown column projects_id`

So I tried

```
" ON projects.projects_id = projectfiles_projectID";
```

But still the same error

I then started experimenting, and tried (as a test)

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name,userID FROM projects";

$sql .= " LEFT JOIN".
    " (SELECT 
        projectfiles.id as projectfiles_id,
        projectfiles.fileID as projectfiles_fileID,
        projectfiles.projectID as projectfiles_projectID
       FROM projectfiles
       ) AS projectfiles".
    " ON projects.id = projectfiles_projectID";
```

And to my surprise, the LEFT JOIN didn't seem to pick up anything at all.

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name,userID FROM projects";

$sql .= " LEFT JOIN".
    " (SELECT 
        projectfiles.id as projectfiles_id,
        projectfiles.fileID as projectfiles_fileID,
        projectfiles.projectID as projectfiles_projectID
       FROM projectfiles
       ) AS projectfiles".
    " ON projects.id = projectfiles_projectID";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res) die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    $rownum = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        print_r($row);
        echo "<br/><br/>";
    $rownum++;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: problem]

Which is weird because there is only one row in `projects` but 3 in `projectfiles` with that projectID... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use instance of column name in ON condition and while selecting also, it will give you correct solution. Don't need to complicate by using AS. Show some your sample data and required o/p.

Comment: Do you want single record with Projects table then use DISTINCT.

Comment: @Jack here's the output from my initial query: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/CItja.png). So basically I want that, but without the obsolete (id, userID, name) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select only from the `projectfiles` table:

```
$sql = "SELECT projectfiles.*,
        projects.id as projects_id
       FROM projects";

// rest of the code is the same
```

**Update**

```
$sql = "SELECT projectfiles.* FROM projects";
// rest of the code is the same
```

Comment: @natli you're welcome :) didn't originally think it would be that easy hehe

Answer (score 1):

Use short form of the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT projects.id,projects.name,projects.userID FROM projects LEFT JOIN
       projectfiles ON projects.id = projectfiles.projectID";
```

Comment: Didn't work, I still get 3 rows from projects with no data from the left join.

Comment: You edited your answer. I don't want to use the short form because I want to use the AS keyword on all data retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*, pf.id, pf.fileId
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN projectfiles pf 
on p.id = pf.projectID
```

You can use "as" to do as you will then. No need for a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.name,p.userID FROM projects p";

$sql .= " LEFT JOIN".
    " projectfiles pf ".
    " ON p.id = p.projectID";
```

Comment: I think you mean `" ON p.id = pf.projectID";` ? And it didn't work, I still get 3 rows from projects with no data from the left join.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT prj.id as prjId,
    prj.name as prjName,
    prj.userID as prjUid,
    pf.id as pfId, 
    pf.fileID as pfFileId, 
    pf.projectID as pfProjecId 
FROM projects as prj 
LEFT JOIN projectfiles AS pf 
ON prj.id = pf.projectID";
```